# How to configure retention period for a Azure Blob folder?

Tags: sql-server, azure, blob, retention, azure-sql-managed-instance

How to configure retention period for a Azure Blob folder?

I want to set a 7 days retention period for SQL Server log backups in Azure. How to configure in Azure Blob Storage?

Comment: Hi @AVB, If my answer is helpful for you, please accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the data sets/blob [lifecycle management policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-lifecycle-management-concepts?tabs=azure-portal#add-or-remove-a-policy) for Your Storage.

The lifecycle management policy lets you:

- Transition blobs from cool to hot immediately if accessed to optimize
  for performance
- Transition blobs, blob versions, and blob snapshots to a cooler
  storage tier (hot to cool, hot to archive, or cool to archive) if not
  accessed or modified for a period of time to optimize for cost
- **Delete blobs, blob versions, and blob snapshots at the end of their
  lifecycles**
- Define rules to be run once per day at the storage account level
- Apply rules to containers or a subset of blobs (using name prefixes
  or blob index tags as filters)

For example:
[image]

Ref the Portal guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-lifecycle-management-concepts?tabs=azure-portal#azure-portal-list-view

HTH.